# Мгновенное создания файла csv

Tags: c#, unity3d, потоки-данных, unity3d-editor

Мне нужно проверить есть ли файл по пути, если нет то создать его и сразу же добавить туда текст, но вот проблема, файл создается но текст не добавляется и только при следующим запуске добавляется текст который должен был бы быть если бы файл существовал.

```
if (File.Exists (Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + FileName + ".csv")) {
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + FileName + ".csv", Resources.Load<TextAsset>(FileName).text + "000\n");
    } else 
    {
        File.Create(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + FileName + ".csv");
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + FileName + ".csv", "111\n");
    }
```

Но на выходе при записи после создании выдает ошибку

> IOException: Sharing violation on path C:\Users\Rostik\Documents\untitled47\Shashki2d\Assets\Resources\Ro1.csv
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:124)
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool,System.Text.Encoding)
>   System.IO.File.WriteAllText (System.String path, System.String contents, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:626)
>   System.IO.File.WriteAllText (System.String path, System.String contents) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:621)
>   CSVRo.Awake () (at Assets/Resources/CSVRo.cs:17)

**Вопрос:** как можно при создании записать туда текст?

Comment: возможно еще когда файл создается, он не освобождается, а вы уже пытаетесь в него писать. попробуйте закрыть его принудительно или создание файла в using

Comment: Sharing violation - файл заблокирован. Возможны три причины 1) файлик какой-то программой (например excel или notepad), которая удерживает файл, и блокирует запись. Закройте программу которая удерживает файл. Найдите утилиту handles.exe sysinternals от sysinternals - посмотрите кто блокирует файл. 2)Если вы понадеявшись на GC не сделали файлу Close или не обвернули где-то в using - то блокировать может ваша же программа - исправляете ошибку 3)Ещё удерживать может нудный антивирус - делая проверку новосозданого файла. Тогда к файлу нужно обратится попозже, когда антивирус отпустит.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант 4 - если в многопоточности два потока стучат в один файл - одному из будет отказано. Тогда нужно ставить семафоры или статику для блокировки многопоточного доступа.

Comment: А нафига вообще отдельно создавать? WriteAllText сам создаёт файл и записывает в него текст, а если файл есть, то перезаписывает, поэтому достаточно просто его вызвать и уточните, что вам нужно именно этот метод, а не AppendAllText, потому что WriteAllText полностью перезаписывает файл, а Append - добавляет в конец.

Comment: Выкиньте всё, оставьте одну строку: `File.WriteAllText(path, text);` Этот метод сам создаст файл, если его нет. Если есть - откроет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного поправил ваш код. Делает абсолютно то же самое, но чуть более ёмко.

```
var path = "В:\\myFile.txt"; // расширение не важно
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
File.WriteAllText(path, "blablabla");
```

Обращение к файлу таким образом работает корректно, хотя и оставляет поток открытым, после вызова `File.Create()`
Даже при открытом в Notepad'e файле (предположения других пользователей в комментах вопроса), исключений не возникает, пускай в него ничего и не пишется.
Вероятнее всего, где-то еще вызываются потоки, которые пытаются стучаться в файл или поток созданного файла блокирует доступ.
Возможно, поможет изменение строки:

```
File.Create(path).Dispose();
// А дальше код записи в файл.
```

**upd**. Решил поправить ответ, т.к. господа в комментариях к моему ответу дали очень полезные советы.

Можно обойтись без проверки/создания файла(которые создают `FileStream` и который в вашем коде не был утилизирован) и писать все сразу функцией `File.WriteAllLines`, которая создаст файл автоматически, при его отсутствии. Подробнее в [доках](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Метод `File.WriteAllText` сам создаст файл, если его нет. Если есть - откроет. Так что достаточно одной строки кода.

Comment: А замечание про `Dispose` верное. В любом случае нужно подчищать за собой, освобождать все ресурсы.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Я как-то про это забыл :)

Comment: Без `Dispose` точно неправильно, т. к. `File.Create` возвращает незакрытый поток.